# return value of multiprocessing and extract it as an input of another function in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
def func1(a):
    return a**2

def func2(a):
    x= np.zeros(1)
    for i in a:
        x += i
    return x
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool( os.cpu_count())
    results = pool.map(func1, a)
    print(results)
```

and then I need

```
func2(results)
```

This is just a simple example of my problem . Please don't tell me to transfer a to numpy array first because my func2 is way more complicated than this example.
Does anyone know how to do it please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm no multiprocessing expert, but wouldn't `results_2 = pool.starmap(func2, results)` work?

Comment: no it doesnt. Thanks though

Comment: My goal is to use the 'results' as an input of another function. But with 'if __name__ == "__main__"' , I don't know how to do it

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve here? Is your `results` the array you want to process in `func2`? Or do you want to process every result of func1 in func2 individually as soon as the result is ready? Or something else?

Comment: It is  results the array I want to process in func2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something in this direction:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

def func1(n):
    return n ** 2

def func2(a):

    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

    results = pool.map(func1, a)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(results)
    # [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]

    x = np.sum(results)
    return x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    
    out = func2(a)
    print(out)
    # 91
```