# numba :cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'> python

Tags: python, numba

Here is my code.

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np
import time

from pandas.core.common import flatten
from numba import njit
b_wi=[[1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9,10,11]] #b_wi is a subset of x
f_wi=[[5,4,2,7,9],[5,4,3,7,2,3,4]]

# @jit(nopython=True)
def stopF_w(x,b_wi,f,di):
    if di=='left':
        return f[np.searchsorted(-b_wi,-x,side='left')]
    if di=='right':
        return f[np.searchsorted( b_wi, x,side='right')]
    # this f :need to be an element in f_nslst
    #b_wi :need to be an element in b_wilst

@njit(parallel=True)
def averageF_w(x,b_wilst,f_nslst,di):
    a=np.zeros(x.shape[0])
    for b_wi,f in zip(b_wilst,f_nslst):
        a[:]  += stopF_w(x,np.asarray(b_wi),np.asarray(f),di)
    return a

intval= np.unique(list(flatten(b_wi)))
x=np.concatenate(([-10000],(intval[:-1]+intval[1:])/2,[10000]))  #b_wi is a subset of x. That is why I can use this.
averageF_w(x,b_wi,f_wi,'right')
```

It raises error: TypingError: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>.
Does anyone know how to fix it please?
Thank you very much.

Comment: please post only the absolutely relevant part of your code

Comment: I am sorry which part do you think is not relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems to handle: first, you've commented out the `@jit` decorator of your first function, `stopF_w`.

If you uncomment it, you'll resolve your current error. Unfortunately, you will immediately run into several other errors. if your numba version is up to date, you'll see an error pertaining to "reflected lists".

Basically, your inputs `b_wi` and `f_wi` are lists of variable length lists, which cannot be converted into uniform numpy arrays. E.g.: if instead of `[[1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9,10,11]]`, if `b_wi` was something like `[[1,2,3, 4, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]` (easily convertible to an array of shape (2, 5) then it would work without any problems. To get your variable length lists to work with numba, you need to rely on a [Typed List](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html#feature-typed-list), which is a bit cumbersome.

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np
import time

from pandas.core.common import flatten
from numba import njit

from numba.typed import List

b_wi=[[1,2,3,4], [6,7,8,9,10,11]]
f_wi=[[5,4,2,7,9], [5,4,3,7,2,3,4]]

###########################
# Create typed Lists
###########################
b_wi_nb = List()
for i in range(len(b_wi)):
    b = List()
    for j in range(len(b_wi[i])):
        b.append(b_wi[i][j])
    b_wi_nb.append(b)

f_wi_nb = List()
for i in range(len(f_wi)):
    f = List()
    for j in range(len(f_wi[i])):
        f.append(f_wi[i][j])
    f_wi_nb.append(f)
```

We will use `b_wi_nb` and `f_wi_nb` as inputs later on.

Another problem: the function `stopF_w` has two "if" blocks. If neither condition is met, is may return None, which is unacceptable to numba for your use case. So alongside uncommenting the jit decorator, you also need to change the condition to if-else, or if-elif-else as applicable.

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def stopF_w(x,b_wi,f,di):
    if di=='left':
        return f[np.searchsorted(-b_wi,-x,side='left')]
    else:
        return f[np.searchsorted( b_wi, x,side='right')]
```

After the above changes, numba should work.

```
@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def averageF_w(x, b_wilst, f_nslst, di):
    a = np.zeros(x.shape[0])
    for b_wi, f in zip(b_wilst,f_nslst):
        a  += stopF_w(x, np.asarray(b_wi), np.asarray(f), di)
    return a

intval= np.unique(list(flatten(b_wi)))
x=np.concatenate(([-10000],(intval[:-1]+intval[1:])/2,[10000]))

##############################
# initial compiles
##############################
stopF_w(np.arange(1),np.arange(1),np.arange(1),'right')
averageF_w(np.arange(10),np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3),np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3),'right')
##############################



averageF_w(x, b_wi_nb, f_wi_nb,'right')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you long answer. The thing is , the length of inputs b_wi and f_wi are meant to be different. That is why this problem is so tricky for me. I thought about using multiprocessing package. But I couldn't figure out the problem in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67909376/return-value-of-multiprocessing-and-extract-it-as-an-input-of-another-function-i

Comment: I tried your solution. It works now ! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I have another question please. As I need to transfer the list using List(). Then the computation time will increase because of the transformation. DO you happen to know how to deal with this please?  When I tried your solution in my practical problem, The time increase a lot because the length of my list is too large.

Comment: Not sure if it'll work, but you can try installing a previous version of numba, that has no problem with normal list of lists. According to https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html, seems like maybe versions < 0.44.0 may work. Apart from this, yes, multiprocessed pooling seems to be the more suitable solution. Create a mp.Pool inside averageF_w, and map on stopF_w.

Comment: but then I cannot create pool  inside averageF_w because I need 'if __name__ == "__main__":
 '

Comment: You don't really need \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main_\_\"; it is optional in python3. And you can create a pool anywhere and inside any function, not just below main : )

Comment: Sorry I don't see any example without it work yet. Could you share a link with example please?

Comment: It creates'RuntimeError' without this ' main' thingy.